# set variable 2 digits in a for loop

Tags: php, html, select

I'm having an stupid issue here; I'm trying to make in a form, a select with the time the user starts, and the time they finish, so logically, I want to display the time as:
00
01
02.. I mean, 2 digit

But although I put 00 for the initial value of $i, it displays only 1 digit anyway!

Is it any way I can set it to two digits?

[image]

Thanks!!

```
<div class="interval">
                 <input type="checkbox" id="interval_check"/>
                <div id="desde">
                  De: <select class="hores" name="hores" disabled>
                    <?php for ($i = 00; $i <= 23; $i++) : ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                  <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>:<select class="minuts" name="minuts" disabled>
                    <?php for ($i = 00; $i <= 45; $i+=15) : ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                  <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>
                </div> <div id="fins">
                fins: <select class="hores" name="hores" disabled>
                    <?php for ($i = 00; $i <= 23; $i++) : ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                  <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>:<select class="minuts" name="minuts" disabled>
                    <?php for ($i = 00; $i <= 45; $i+=15) : ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                  <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>
                 </div>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to create the string for you.

```
 <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) : ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
         <?php echo sprintf("%02d", $i); ?>
       </option>
 <?php endfor; ?>
```

this will add a 0 if the string is less than 2 characters.  I'm presuming that you don't care about the value.